# How do i reverse alias command?

Tags: sudo, docker, localhost

I executed this command :

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 10.200.10.1/24
```

I think this changes my localhost address and I think my dockers seem to stop working because of this. Is there a way to reverse this change?

Comment: What OS is this from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you executed is only temporarily. If you reboot your system the alias is gone.
Another Way to do it is
`sudo ifconfig lo0 -alias 10.200.10.1/24`